# How can i define a variable with a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

EDIT 2 : This is my first post on stock overflow and although I sometimes have some bad, questions to ask. i thought id at least fix the formatting considering I can not delete this.

I essentially wanted to automate variable creation , although at the time I did not not such things as arrays existed surprisingly.

I want to automate the creation of this variable

```js
var l = createSprite(200,200);
```

I want to be able to define one variable , with another like this :

```js
var count = 5;
var l + count = 1;
count++;
var l + count = 2;
```

```js
var l=30 
var l + "foo" = 40`
```

if I were to run this, lfoo would be returned undefined. Why? Is this impossible? If so how can i automate
defining variables?

Comment: what do you want in result ?

Comment: Why do you want that? You can create the new variable directly with `var lfoo = 40`.

Comment: Are you trying to make `30foo` variable?

Comment: you can't define variables like this. you have to define it through writing the absolute name for them. But to call them you can use window["l"+"foo"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: Why do you need that? To me it smells like bad code..

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object and use `l` as part of the key for the access.

- [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)
- [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [Property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
var l = 30 ,
    object = { [l + "foo"]: 40 };

console.log(object[l + "foo"]);
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define variables like this. You have to define it through writing the absolute name for them. But to call them you can use window["l"+"foo"].

```js
var l = 40;
var lfoo = 30;
console.log(window["l"]+"...."+window["l"+"foo"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use window to declare global variables

```
var str = 'l' + 'foo';
window[str] = 40;
//Then you can access lfoo directly
```